# Table view does not update when calling from completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I built a rename dialog to change selected list (table) entries. The rename dialog has a delagate in the main view. If the dialog is closed by clicking "save" then some database operations should be executed and the table must be refreshed:

```
func finishedShowing(_ vc : UIViewController, _ result : Bool) {
    if result {
        vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            if vc is RenameViewController {
                // do something in the database and update the table model
                self.refreshLibrary()
            }
        })
    }
}

private func refreshLibrary() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

My problem is that the database is changed successfully so the completion handler is triggered correctly and also the table model (an array of strings in my case) is changed (I debugged it) but the table view does not update. It only shows the old version.

Comment: you could try to reload the data on the main thread. I suppose the completion handler is calling back on some arbitrary thread, and UI updates should be done on the main one.

Comment: Is that block called in main thread? At least, do the ` self.tableView.reloadData()` in main thread (all UI related stuff need to be done in main thread).

Comment: your method is called or not `refreshLibrary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the reload function inside the main thread:

```
private func refreshLibrary() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```